# Situation: Balloon Note Removal Program

Tags: mortgage, refinance

We recently applied to remove a balloon note and the process calls for a property evaluation.

What if the property is not worth the amount left on the mortgage balance?

Can the bank refuse to continue our payment schedule?

What should we do if this happens? Our mortgage has reached its maturity.

Comment: The second sentence is... confusing.

Comment: Since the "*mortgage has reached its maturity*" there is no more "*payment schedule*" to follow.  It's like dying: there is no more breathing after dying, because... you're dead.

Comment: Thank you; I am aware of that part. However, how would the bank proceed if the home is not worth the amount owed?  Thanks.

Comment: @RonJohn I believe that first "is" is supposed to be "if": "what if the property is not worth the amount left on the mortgage balance?", i.e. it's underwater.

Comment: So you need to refinancing the mortgage?  How old is it? Was it an ARM (I'm presuming so, since you said "balloon payment")?